# terraform replace reference value with workspace

Tags: amazon-web-services, reference, terraform

hi can some one please  help me reg reference vpc id in aws terraform with using workspace

1. I have created vpc dev and stage. using vpc module and am able to read  using

working one
module.application_vpc_dev[0].vpc_id

want use workspace instead static value
Not working          module.application_vpc_${terraform.workspace}[0].vpc_id

is this right syntax can someone please help me

Comment: That will never work. It is not possible.

Comment: thanks, @MarkoE   yes seems like its not supported,  i need to use a different method to work with this

Comment: thanks that's correct   "echo "[Database: Indiv Dataset (id: FTRD). (secyrutty: true) ]" | sed -n 's/.*id: \([^)]*\).*/\1/p'
"   echo "[Database: Indiv Dataset (id: FTRD). (secyrutty: true) ]" | grep -oP '(?<=\(id: )\w+'